# Continuing to eat somewhere else because of the das of bal habayis

Tags: halacha, food, meal-seudah

When someone starts a seudah they may have das (have in mind) to continue eating the seudah somewhere else; if they do, they sometimes can do so without saying a new beracha (see Rama, Orach Chayim 178:1). What about if the person themselves didn't have this in mind; however, the bal habayis, the one who is the "head" of the meal and providing the meal, had in mind that he (along with whoever else) would continue eating the meal somewhere else. Does "das bal habayis" help in such a case?

Comment: You might wish to [edit] into your question why you think the intent of the homeowner (or similar) may have anything to do with it. (E.g., do we see _daas baal habayis_ working in lieu of an individual eater's _daas_ in any other case?) Without that, the question seems groundless.